# Why is Electric Field at the surface of a hollow conducting metal sphere always outwards (positive charge on the sphere)?

Tags: electrostatics

I meant why are electric lines of forces outwards and not inwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because electric field points directly outwards from the charged region,simple.And according to our definition,electric lines of forces are always directed towards the electric field.So,for positive charge,outwards and inwards for negative charge.

Again,they are normal to the surface as on the surface of conductor at the point you are looking for the charge must be evenly distributed. If electric field is not normal,say it is slanted at an angle, if that is the case then there will be a component of the electric field in the direction of the tangent of the surface of the conductor. And if there is electric field on the surface then the charges inside the conductor will move across the electric field which is clearly not possible in equilibrium,i.e,after the conductor has attained the equipotential state of its surface.

Comment: Ya,but why is the field outward???

Comment: You want to know why outwards,not inwards-or why normally outwards

Comment: Yes, i want to know why it's outward...

Comment: Then you should ask it clearly in your question,as your question seems to look for an entirely different thing

Comment: Now I've edited my answer

Comment: So for a hollow conductor(sphere) with negative charge,will the field be inwards???

Comment: Certainly it will be